# View not getting updated when API returns data

Tags: reactjs

Using react functional component I'm trying to implement load more functionality.

On initial load `fetchInitialTransactions` is called and API sends `10` records.

When load more is clicked `fetchLoadMoreTransactions` is called with the `loadMoreCount` value is set as `2` and API send `6` records.

So use should see 10 + 6 total of 16 records, but in the view it is displaying only last `6` records.

Please help, below is my code.

```
 const handleLoadMoreButtonClick = (e: MouseEvent) => {
    setIsLoadMoreSpinnerVisible(true);
    setLoadMoreCount(loadMoreCount + 1);
    fetchLoadMoreTransactions();
  };
    
  const fetchInitialTransactions = async () => {
    const response: any = await fetchTransactions();
    if (response?.data) {
      setTransactionsList(response?.data);
      groupTransactionsByDate(response?.data);
      setIsLoadMoreSpinnerVisible(false);
      setTransactionAlert(response.data.isNextPageAvailable);
    }
    return response;
  };
 
  const fetchLoadMoreTransactions = async () => {
    const response: any = await fetchTransactions();
    if (response?.data) {
      transactionsList.transactionDetails.concat(...response.data.transactionDetails);
      setTransactionsList(transactionsList);
      groupTransactionsByDate(transactionsList);
      setIsLoadMoreSpinnerVisible(false);
      setTransactionAlert(response.data.isNextPageAvailable);
    }
    return response;
  };
 
  const fetchTransactions = async () => {
    if (accountDetails) {
      const response = await postAPIRequestCall(`${API_URL_PREFIX}/cards/transactionList`,
        {
          CardNumber: accountDetails.encryptedCardNumber,
          PageNumber: loadMoreCount,
          FromDate: startDate,
          ToDate: endDate,
        });
      return response;
    }
    return null;
  };
 
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchInitialTransactions();
  }, [accountDetails, loadMoreCount]);
```

**UPDATE**

When load more is clicked in `fetchLoadMoreTransactions` `response?.data` is still pointing to last 10 records.

Comment: imo, you've to save the updated list to the `transactionsList` like: `transactionsList.transactionDetails = transactionsList.transactionDetails.concat(...response.data.transactionDetails);` because the concat just return the result but does not updates the actual ref.

Comment: Can you please verify that you are just able to see the last 6 and not the initial 10?
Because looking at the attached code you are just concatenating to  `transactionDetails` and not even trying to modify `transactionList`.
Also, concat method doesn't modify the original array.

Comment: @KiranParajuli - tried your method still I could see only the last 6 records in the screen

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of setState (i.e. `setTransactionsList`) is that it does the mutation/modification for you. You are not supposed to do `transactionsList.transactionDetails.concat` outside of `setTransactionsList`. Instead, try this:

```
setTransactionsList(current => ({ ...current,
  transactionDetails: 
    current.transactionDetails.concat(response.data.transactionDetails)
  }
));
```

The code above assumes that `current.transactionDetails` and `response.data.transactionDetails` are arrays.

Comment: above code is not working, `A spread argument must either have a tuple  or be passed to a rest`

Comment: I forgot about how arrow functions treat `{}`. It needed to be `({})` instead. My bad.